# Objective C - NSRegularExpression with specific substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, macos, nsregularexpression

I have an `NSString` which I am checking if there is an `NSLog` and then I comment it out. 
I am using `NSRegularExpression` and then looping through result.
The code:

```
-(NSString*)commentNSLogFromLine:(NSString*)lineStr {

    NSString  *regexStr =@"NSLog\\(.*\\)[\\s]*\\;";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

    NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:lineStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [lineStr length])];

    NSMutableString *mutStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:lineStr];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *textCheck in arrayOfAllMatches) {

        if (textCheck) {
            NSRange matchRange = [textCheck range];
            NSString *strToReplace = [lineStr substringWithRange:matchRange];
            NSString *commentedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/*%@*/",[lineStr substringWithRange:matchRange]];
            [mutStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:strToReplace withString:commentedStr options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:matchRange];

            NSRange rOriginal = [mutStr rangeOfString:@"NSLog("];
            if (NSNotFound != rOriginal.location) {
                [mutStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"NSLog(" withString:@"DSLog(" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:rOriginal];
            }
        }
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:mutStr];

}
```

The problem is with the test case:

```
NSString *str = @"NSLog(@"A string"); NSLog(@"A string2")"
```

Instead of returning `"/*DSLog(@"A string");*/ /*DSLog(@"A string2")*/"` it returns: `"/*DSLog(@"A string"); NSLog(@"A string2")*/"`.

The issue is how the `Objective-C` handles the regular expression. I would expected 2 results in `arrayOfAllMatches` but instead that I am getting only one. Is there any way to ask `Objective-C` to stop on the first occurrence  of `);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the regular expression. You are searching for .* inside the parentheses, which causes it to include the first close parenthesis, continue through the second NSLog statement, and go all the way to the final close parentheses.

So what you want to do is something like this:

```
NSString  *regexStr =@"NSLog\\([^\\)]*\\)[\\s]*\\;";
```

That tells it to include everything inside the parenthesis except for the ) character. Using that regex, I get two matches. (note that you omitted the final ; in your string sample).